# Android WebRTC client with pre-encoded H.264 video stream

Tags: android, webrtc

I have a video stream source that sends bytes of H.264-encoded video.  I'd like to build an application with Android's WebRTC classes, to send this video stream to a WebRTC peer.  These built-in classes seem to only support raw video sources... not video already processed by a codec.

I simply need to create an offer with only one video codec/bitrate configuration.  For my use case, I don't need to autoscale the bandwidth usage, nor offer any codecs other than the original H.264 stream of bytes.

Is there a way to utilize the built-in Android WebRTC classes for this?  If not, is there another set of WebRTC classes?  Or, must I re-implement something to create that SDP offer and do all the peer connectivity and what not?

Comment: why not use data channels for that ?

Comment: @peetonn That's an option, but at the time I wanted the WebRTC client to be compatible with others, along with all their hardware decoding and what not.  I've long since given up on that project.  I suspect it isn't reasonably possible.