# Sending already encoded frames through WebRTC

Tags: c++, webrtc, h.264, live-streaming, vp8

I'm using native WebRTC source code (branch M62). Is it possible to pass already encoded frames (H264/VP8) directly to transport layers - in other words - how to skip the encoder ?

I know, that was possible in earlier WebRTC versions/branches - it was enough to send enecoded frames from VideoCapturer instance to MediaEngine class. It seems that in M62 it is much more complex.

Thanks for yours answers/suggestions.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/42015472/362536  At least on Android, after consulting with a handful of devs on this, it was crazy difficult to try to insert your own encoded stream.  Perhaps you'll have better luck poking at GStreamer's WebRTC implementation.  https://opensource.com/article/19/1/gstreamer